# How can I select my font awesome icons in CSS?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Sorry for posting such a simple question, but I've tried everything I can think of. How can I select my font-awesome icons in css? I'm trying to make them into an inline list, and do some other styles, but am struggling to properly select them.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <ul class="social-icons list-inline">
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>  
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using skeleton and am thinking it's messing me up a bit with doing the selectors right as it's my first time using it.

Comment: If I understand correctly.. you want style each icon particularly like .fa-twitter, .fa-facebook etc?

Comment: @j08691 I tried using .social-icons and .list-inline, but I'm basically just wondering what the proper/standard way to do it would be. I'm fairly new to web design and am still a bit confused as to using css selectors properly

Comment: You can use the same class selectors in your CSS to add/modify styles: `.fa-twitter { margin:4px }`

Comment: In your CSS stylesheet, did you define CSS rules for `.twelve`, `.columns`, `.social-icons`, `.list-inline`, or are you using some CSS framework like Bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML looks fine. I think you just forgot to include the Font Awesome stylesheet.

Then, if you want to modify a particular class like making the list inline, just do:

```css
.fa-twitter {
  font-size: 50px !important;
}

.list-inline li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <ul class="social-icons list-inline">
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>  
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @bfunphoto If what you want is making the list inline, see the updated answer. Or let me know what you're actually looking to do..

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectors .fa-twitter, .fa-facebook, .fa-instagram, .fa-linkedin... here's the fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15521/"

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15521/"
```

Comment: I guess specifically I'm having trouble selecting them ALL so I can put them inline

Comment: The list is already inline because of ul.list-inline class. You can select all icons by selector ".social-icons .fa"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to style all of your FA icons then the selector you want is .fa

.fa {display:inline;}